# How can I display the selectedValue (from database) in a dropdown-field from the Edit method in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdownlistview

In the following code of an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project, the `Get` action method `Edit (...)` is displaying a dropdown list of zipcodes. It seems that by default, the dropdown displays the first zipcode in the list (i.e. 1301) as the selected value.

If I want to display the selected value from database in the dropdown list, how can I achieve it from action method `Edit(...)` without creating a view model?

I have a rather complex data model, where zipcodes and city is members in the table Shop, but that table has a many-to-many relationship with product by a conjunction table ProductShop. I'm a beginner so I have been trying to follow this tutorial, but it doesn't get me so far. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0
This is my `Edit` get method in the controller:

```
// GET: Products/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var product = await _context.Product
            .Include(p => p.Brand)
            .Include(p => p.Price)
            .Include(p => p.ProductCategory)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Category)
            .Include(p => p.ProductShop)
                .ThenInclude(ps => ps.Shop)
            .Include(s => s.ProductShop)
                .ThenInclude(ps => ps.Shop)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.Zip)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (product == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ViewData["BrandId"] = new SelectList(_context.Brand, "Id", "BrandName", product.BrandId);

    // this is the method where I want to display zipcodes with the help from viewbag
    ViewData["ZipId"] = new SelectList(_context.Zipcode.ToList(), "Id", "Zip", product.ProductShop.FirstOrDefault().Shop.Zip.Id);

    PopulateSelectedCategories(product);
    return View(product);
}
```

My dropdown list in the view:

```
@model Vegetarian_Products.Models.DB.Product
@*@model Vegetarian_Products.ViewModels.ProductDetailsVM*@
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
//....

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ProductShop.FirstOrDefault().Shop.Zip.Zip" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ProductShop.FirstOrDefault().Shop.Zip.Zip" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ZipId">  
                        </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ProductShop.FirstOrDefault().Shop.Zip.Zip" class="text-danger" />
                </div>

 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Model class for zipcodes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vegetarian_Products.Models.DB {
    public partial class Zipcode {
        public Zipcode() {
            Shop = new HashSet<Shop>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tilføj postnr")]
        [DisplayName("Postnr")]
        public int Zip { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("By")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Shop> Shop { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Screenshot of Edit View running, and there is no selected value from database:

[image: EditView running - no selectedValue]

Model of table-relations:

[image: Table-relations]

Comment: Are you sure that `product.ProductShop.FirstOrDefault().Shop.Zip.Id` return correct `Id`?

Comment: Since you have a intermediate table called ProductShop which establishes the relationship between Product and Shop, I don't see which value you would want to be selected in a many to many (n to n) relationship.

Comment: @Genusatplay Yes, I've been trying to run debug and the correct Zipcode (5230) does go through. It's just something wrong in my way of displaying that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try create SelectList like this

```
var selectedId = product.ProductShop.FirstOrDefault()?.Shop.Zip.Id;
ViewBag.ZipId = await _context.Zipcode
                              .Select(w => new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                              Value = w.Id.ToString(),
                                              Text = w.Zip.ToString(),
                                              Selected = w.Id == selectedId
                                            })
                               .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. and it also helped, when I changed my taghelper to this in view: `@Html.DropDownList("ZipId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 0):

Having a selected value in this situation would only make sense if Product and Shop were related directly in a 1 to 1 relationship or if Product was related to Shop in a N to 1 relationship.

Since a Product can be related to many Shops and a Shop be related to many Products, it doesn't make sense to have a select field with a selected value in either View.

If I understood this model correctly, the way you want to display this is by having a list of Shops in the Product Edit page and a list of Products in the Shop Edit page.

So I suggest you break this list into a Selected List ViewData and a Unselected List ViewData instead of bundling them all together, then using a way of adding and removing items which would visually move them from one list to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not sure what you exactly mean by having a Selected List ViewData and Unselected list Viewdata? Is it possible to show me an example of that?
It is correct that I want to have a list of Shops for one product, and a list of Products for one Shop.
But I do get the correct zipcode (selectedValue) if I don't make the taghelper into a dropdownlist. But just like this: `<input asp-for="ProductShop.FirstOrDefault().Shop.Zip.Zip" class="form-control" />`